# Why is this bitwise operator resulting false?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

```
int u = 21;
int v = 10;

if (u && v) printf(“ Time to move on!! ”);
if (u & v) printf(“Do it today!! \n”);
```

This only prints "Time to move on!!" which makes sense because both u and v are true in the first if statement but for "if (u & v)" I'm not sure how it's determining whether that's true or false. I get it &'s the two binary representations of 21 and 10 but then what? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

21 in binary is `10101`, whereas 10 in binary is `01010`. A bitwise `&` returns `00000`, or `0`, which is `false`.

Comment: okay and say if it were 23 so 10111 and 10 so 01010 which would give 00010, would this result in 1 so true?

Comment: It would result in 2 (`00010` has a `1` in the `2`s place). Anything non-zero results in `true`.